meaning of だからさ in this context
I checked some translations and I got something like "you see, I'm a mage..." or "you know, I'm a mage...".
I"m still not 100% sure



What makes you think だからさ would have a special meaning other than what it means literally ? nounだ + から is "because (I am) noun", and さ is a speech particle that doesn't add concrete meaning.


This だから is "because".
This さ is a filler particle that adds little to the semantics of the sentence. Instead, it's used to keep the listener's attention and maintain the flow of the conversation. It can appear a lot in one sentence, so you don't always have to translate it, but you can optionally translate it into English as "you see", "you know", "well" or "um". If you know ね is used like this, this さ is the same.
By the way, 魔法職 is RPG jargon that generically refers to all magic-using jobs/classes. It includes not only mages but also sages, necromancers, warlocks, priests, clerics, and so on.

The literal meaning of 私魔法職だからさ is "Because I'm a (spell)caster, (you know)".

thank you for the detailed explanation. so when I add the second part of the sentence of would sound someggjnf like this;  "(you know) I'm a spell caster, so it would help me out alot of if had a strong front line fighter "

@torajuro Yes, that's correct.
